# ¿Como enviar cabeceras desde php a web service SOAP en java?

Tags: php, xampp, soap, jboss

Desde mi servidor xampp consumo un web service SOAP que esta en un servidor JBOSS. Cuando lo consumo me llegan bien los parametros de usuario y contraseña para autenticacion, pero envio otro parametro como cabecera y este no llega. Si consumo el web service utilizando SOAP UI y envio la cabecera si llega.

Este es el codigo que esta en mi servidor xampp para consumir el web service:

```
    <?php
$soap_client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8081/miproyecto/WebServiceBean?wsdl",array('trace' => true));
$ns = "http://mins/";

$auth = new stdClass();
$auth = array('Authorization'=>'aGVucnEVTJOemc1');

$header = new SoapHeader($ns, 'Authorization', $auth);
$soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$usu="muusuario"; 
$passwd="mipass";
$entradasVal = array("usuario"=>$usu,"contrasenia"=>$passwd);
$param=array('arg0'=>$entradasVal);

try {
    $result=$soap_client->__soapCall('validar', $param);
    var_dump($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas enviar dos o más encabezados, [**`__setSoapHeaders`**](http://php.net/manual/es/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php) también puede recibir un arreglo. Es decir:

```
$headers = array();

$headers[] = new SoapHeader($ns, 'name1', $value1);
$headers[] = new SoapHeader($ns, 'name2', $value2);
$headers[] = new SoapHeader($ns, 'name3', $value3);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @PaulVargas
Pues solo necesito enviar un encabezado. Igual así no la envía.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que no lo envía o que tu productor (en Java) no lo procesa?